# iOS App Clip: disable auto showing App Banner on App Clip Launch?

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

When I launch my App Clip for the first time, iOS decides to show an app banner automatically. Our app clip is essentially the full version of the app so we don't want our users to upgrade to the app immediately.

Is there a way to hide this on launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. AFAIK Apple didn't intend App Clips to be a brand new distribution method outside the App Store.

They're just meant to be slices of a full app, so there's no way to turn off this banner that nudges you to download the complete app (that I could find).